# Read rtf metadata with python

Tags: python, module, metadata, rtf

I need to read the width of colums in one .rtf file. I have not found any information which Python module is able to do this. Can you please help how to sort it out?

Thank you!

Here it is an example of  [rtf file:](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgRDvy-wKDjUySBQGe9M-1D44sMD)

Comment: To clarify your question: Consider adding a sample of the RTF file, Maybe you have to write your own parser, or extend an existing parser class. (Me not being an python expert)

Comment: Thank you. Added it.